# Doctrine2 best way to Populate Entities From Zend Form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-form

What's the bets way to populate an Entity in Doctrine from data that I receive from a user form which is a Zend Form.

```
Class User {
     private $id, $name, $password;
}
```

And a form with corresponding:

```
<input name="name"> <input name="password">
```

Is there a nice way to assign data from the form (Zend Form) to the User Entity without hard coding every mutator method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *can* use [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to set property values in an entity. If you have an array, with keys identical to the entity's property names, it wouldn't be too hard to just iterate over them. Make sure you sanitize your input array first though.

For a complex example, take a look at \Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::createEntity()

Comment: I was thinking about that. I'll probably take this route

Comment: Don't forget about the ClassMetaData instances, they already hold reflection information about entities.